# Correct handling of deletion of a UIDocument in another instance of your app with iCloud

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, icloud, uidocument

I've found out, that I can detect the deletion of a UIDocument on the iCloud through following method:

```
- (void)accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completionHandler
```

This method gets correctly called, but I don't know what to do in the method.
At the moment I close the document, if it's still open, but it looks like the document gets saved on the old path while closing, so the document reappears.

I have already searched intensely, but I haven't found anything neither in the Apple doc nor in any forum.

Has somebody made similar experience or has somebody handled the deletion correctly?

Comment: It looks like Apple's Lister sample app just dismisses the view controller without closing the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out, that I close the document 2 times and before closing it the 2nd time, I save it.
I have remove the saveToURL method and now it works as expected.

For all who want to detect a deletion:
Overwrite this method in your subclass of UIDocument with following code:

```
    - (void)accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *errorOrNil))completionHandler
{
    sceneLampDocument* presentedDocument = self;
    [presentedDocument closeWithCompletionHandler: ^(BOOL success) {
        NSError* error = nil;
        if (!success)
        {
            NSDictionary* userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"Could not close document that is being deleted on another device",
                                      NSLocalizedDescriptionKey, nil];
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain: @"some_suitable_domain"
                                        code: 101
                                    userInfo: userInfo];
        }

        completionHandler(error);  // run the passed in completion handler (required)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                       {
                           //[super accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];

                           NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self forKey:@"document"];
                           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"documentDeletedOnAnotherDevice"
                                                                               object: self
                                                                             userInfo: userInfo];
                       });
        }];
}
```

I hope this will help someone

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Apple docs were not too clear whether `UIDocument` would close itself or I should do that in my subclass. By the way, instead of posting a notification you can listen to `UIDocumentStateChangedNotification` and check if `documentState` contains `UIDocumentStateClosed`. One less notification to define :-)